# Points of finite order of elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

In p.192 The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, the proposition3.1 is described when $m$ is relatively prime to $p=char(k)$.
How is this fact when $p|m$?

For example,Example3.3.2.

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be the elliptic curve

\begin{equation}
E:y^2= x^3+3.
\end{equation}
And the discriminant $\mathbb{\Delta}=-2^4\cdot3^5 \neq0$ mod $p\geq5$.

Then $|\tilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_5)|=6$ , $|\tilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_7)|=13$.

From these calculations, this book concludes that $E(\mathbb{Q})$ has no nontrivial torsion.

However , according to the proposition 3.1 ,I think that this proves only when m is relatively prime 5 or 7.

Comment: what is proposition 3.1?

Comment: Isn't the point that the torsion subgroup would inject into both the reduced curves (because they have good reduction), and since $6$ and $13$ are relatively prime there can't be any torsion.